# Calculate GL classification from Exact Online real-time in my Excel report with Invantive Control for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

I like to get three columns in my Excel report for Exact Online with Invantive Control. I like to calculate the GL classification code and the GL classification description using as input to the Excel formula the following parameters using formulas:

- Division code.
- General Ledger account code.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the GL Classification Code using:

`=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_CODE(576096;"8000")`

Where the first parameter is the division code and the second parameter is the General Ledger Account Code. Please note that you need the double quotes around the code, especially when the General Ledger account code starts with a '0', such as "0100". Replace ';' by ',' when using an English Excel version.

The formula for the GL Classification Description is:

`=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_DESCRIPTION(576096;"8000")`